# Magento 2.0.2 installation, fatal error: DOMDocument

Tags: magento2, php, fatal-error

I am trying to install Magento 2.0.2 on a GoDaddy "Ultimate Linux Hosting with cPanel" server. When I open the page I am given this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in
>   /home/intx/public_html/dev/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php on
>   line 364

I have tried looking all over and can not figure out what I am supposed to do to fix this.

Answer (score 10):

**Install these 2 extention and restart apache**

```
 sudo apt-get install php7.1-dom
 sudo apt-get install php7.1-xml
 sudo service apache2 restart
```

Note: php version according to your current php version

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a pretty old question, but just in case someone came here (as I did)...

You have to install the php-dom module on your system, on *debianlike* systems:

```
apt-get install php-xml
```

And restart your server:

```
service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue:

> Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in
>   /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php:377

But i installed `php7.0-xml` package which is running

Answer (score 1):

Hi I think that you have used php7.1 version, You can check that by using

```
php -v
```

You should change default php version to php 7.0 use command line

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

then select correct version (php7.0)

Answer (score 1):

for centos 7 (linux)

```
yum install php-xml
```

for ubuntu

```
apt-get install php-xml
```

use sudo if you are not a root user for privileges

Answer (score 1):

Solved:  I realized that the php commands I was executing were run by the php installed on the system, and not the one in use by Xampp. Thus installing the php-xml part solved that issue. I resolved all the subsequent errors in the same way. So far, the app is running ok. Granted, a proper, clean stack would be preferable, but this will do for now.