# I have deleted PHP and re-install it now below error coming /Can't find ini.php file

Tags: magento2, php, dom

[image]Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in /var/www/html/magento211/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php:384
Stack trace:

## 0 /var/www/html/magento211/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php(115): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->_initDom('

## 1 /var/www/html/magento211/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Config/Reader/Dom.php(70): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct('

2 /var/www/html/magento211/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php(149): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Config\Reader\Dom->_createConfigMerger('Magento\Framewo...', '

3 /var/www/html/magento211/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php(130): Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem->_readFiles(Object(Magento\Framework\Config\FileIterator))

4 /var/www/html/magento211/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php(275): Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\File in /var/www/html/magento211/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php on line 384

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M17hB.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cu7H7.png (I can find php/7.1/apache2/php.ini file or php/7.1/cli/php.ini file for any version of php 
(2)[image] also when I run sudo apt-get install php7.1-xml in the end below error coming

Comment: i did sudo apt-get install php7.0-imap
sudo apt-get install php-xml not working

Comment: I did not working -https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105712/magento-2-0-2-installation-fatal-error-domdocument